# Keras - Moderate Accuracy, bad predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I'm doing my first steps into machine learning and trying to do a sign-language machine learning project using the [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist). It is supposed to be able to predict characters in ASL. Here's the data presented by Kaggle.
[Image of Dataset here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpJ7a.png)

My current issue is that I can achieve moderate accuracy that fits the data given by Kaggle using their testing data, but if I try to predict a single image, say a random letter of the alphabet, it will be consistently wrong. Here's my code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD

import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelBinarizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

trainer = read_csv("sign_mnist_train.csv")
labels = trainer["label"].values
trainer = trainer.drop(["label"], axis=1) #


tester = read_csv("sign_mnist_test.csv")
testlabels = tester["label"].values
tester = tester.drop(["label"], axis=1)



def preProcessing(raw, classes):
    OH = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False) # One hot's the labels, can be replaced with LabelBinarizer
    binary = classes.reshape(len(classes), 1)
    binary = OH.fit_transform(binary)   

    images = raw.values

    for c, i in enumerate(images, 0):
        image = np.reshape(i, (28, 28))
        image = image.flatten()
        images[c] = np.array(image)

    return images, binary

def defineModel(): # Builds the layers for our model
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(x_test.shape[1:]), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

    opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
    return model


def testModel(): #Test's a single image, predicting the class.
    model = load_model("my_model.hl5")
    img = load_img("C.jpg", color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(28, 28))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = np.reshape(img, (-1, 28, 28, 1))


    test = model.predict_classes(img)
    print(test)
    test_test = model.predict_proba(img)[0]
    test_test = "%.2f" % (test_test[test]*100)
    print(test_test)



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    data, labels = preProcessing(trainer, labels)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels,  test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_train = x_train/255.0
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))

    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test/255.0
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))



    model = defineModel()

    history =  model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data = (x_test, y_test), epochs=40, verbose=1, batch_size=128)

    model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

    model.save("my_model.hl5")
```

Apologies for the messy code, but essentially I try to break the data into usable parts using Panda, then using Keras/Sklearn to fit the data. I wanted to look deeper and was advised to use accuracy_score in the Sklearn library.

```
   testStuff, testlabels = preProcessing(tester, testlabels)
   testStuff = testStuff.reshape(testStuff.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
   pred = model.predict(testStuff).round()
   print(accuracy_score(testlabels, pred))
```

This showed that my accuracy was only around 70% compared to the 99% model.evaluate posed. Regardless, I still a very low accuracy on random predictions, some of my individual tests were snipped straight from the Kaggle example images. From there, I tried removing layers, increasing/reducing filters on the Conv2d layers to see what happens, but nothing seems to make a difference. I picked up Pyplot to display the graph and I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32gSw.png). I don't see a problematic trend, but I may be looking in the wrong area.

Is it because of overfitting/underfitting? I feel that I am getting something wrong at a fundamental level and could use some tips. Looking at similar questions, they point toward possible indexing issues and otherwise mismanagement of the dataset, I am unsure how to test if these issues are present in my code.  This is my first time using StackOverflow to ask a question so feel free to ask anything since I understand that reading my rambling code/question is confusing.

**Summary: Okay accuracy, bad predictions, why?**

Comment: okay accuracy but bad predictions are generally due to overfitting. Try reducing the learning rate or adding regularization

Comment: Can you post the training and validation accuracy logs or graphs? I am wondering if you are reporting the validation accuracy or the training accuracy? Another point to keep in mind, have you done any preprocessing to the training/validation set that you forgot to do for the testing set?

Answer (score 0):

In general this behaviour often occurs due to overfitting:
Try to tweak your network to have fewer parameters and try to add some regularizations.

Further it could be that your test set only contains a part of the planned real world domain. Meaning that your training set is far away from reality, which also could lead to bad predictions.

A way to tweak your dataset could be data augmentation, I assume it could work very well on this ASL DataSet - but I did not had a deep look.

Data Augmentation is basically an artifical way to increase the size of your dataset, reducing overfitting as well and improves on slight rotations of your hand or other "random" distortions, like different background or different clothing.

A great article about data augmentation can be found here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-deep-learning-4fe21d1a4eb9